# MySQL complicated exclude query

Tags: mysql, relation

I have a bunch of articles

```
+-----------+-------+
| ArticleID | Name  |
+-----------+-------+
| 1         | Bla   |
| 2         | Blub  |
| 3         | Test  |
+-----------+-------+
```

And Prodcutgroups:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| ProductGroupID | Name    |
+-----------+--------------+
| 4              | Group A |
| 5              | Group B |
| 6              | Group C |
+-----------+--------------+
```

And a link table (M:N relation) that links articles with product-groups. Each article can be in many product-groups at the same time but only once per group:

```
+-----------+----------------+
| ArticleID | ProductGroupID |
+-----------+----------------+
| 1         | 4              |
| 1         | 5              |
| 2         | 5              |
| 2         | 6              |
| 3         | 4              |
| 3         | 6              |
+-----------+----------------+
```

My problem is now that I need a query that lets me find out articles that are MISSING in product-group with ID 4.
Usually I would write a PHP Script that loops entire table and checks for values and remembers if product-group-id 4 was not found.

But this seems very sophisticated and annoying as I have this kind of szenario more often here and there.

I cannot use WHERE ProductGroupID NOT IN(4) because when the article is assigned to OTHER product-groups it will find that rows and
the result will NOT tell me wether the article is in this specific group or not.

The result would need to give me only!! Article-ID: 2 as its not in Product-Group with ID 4

I appreciate any helpful advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, using exists logic:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM articles a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM link l
                  WHERE l.ArticleID = a.ArticleID AND l.ProductGroupID = 4);
```

Read in plain English, the above query says to return the name of article for which we cannot find an entry in the link table associated with `ProductGroupID = 4`.